# Writing Query comparing bigdecimal values in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, bigdecimal

When I am appending  "AND  delta d WHERE d.amount >= :amount" in a query I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [amount] did not exist error. Is my query right or needs any modification?

Comment: A query ending with `AND delta d WHERE ...` doesn't seem correct to me. What is this AND? Why not posting the complete query, the code executing it, and the exact and complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Are you optionally appending something else after it? Add spaces at the start and end of the appended string portion. Also @JBNizet is correct about your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> Parameter with that name [amount] did not exist error.

Try to set the parameter before the query execution. For example:

```
...
query.setParameter("amount", amount);
query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes I have done it but still the same error is coming.